# updating Table from Another Table with Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to write a query that will update the schemeid of a row with the id of the matching row from another table.

tblschemes b holds the schemes detail and tblclaims_liberty a holds the claims data and the fields to join on are b.nett_scheme = a.schemename and a.agentcode = b.agentcode

why then id the query below allocating a schemeid to rows of data that do not match the agentcode??

```
update tblclaims_liberty

set tblclaims_liberty.schemeid = tblschemes.id

from tblschemes inner join tblclaims_liberty on tblclaims_liberty.schemename = tblschemes.nett_scheme and tblclaims_liberty.agentcode = tblschemes.agentcode 



where 

    ce_report = 'yes' 
    and (tblclaims_liberty.schemeid != tblschemes.id or schemeid is null) --only updates rows that require updateing instead of 6mil+ lines of data.
```

can someone point me in the right direction?? why is it not recognising the agentcode match?

regards,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
update tblclaims_liberty TLtoUpdate
set TLtoUpdate.schemeid = 
(
select TS.id
from tblschemes TS inner join tblclaims_liberty TL on TL.schemename = TS.nett_scheme and TL.agentcode = TS.agentcode 
where TL.schemeid = TLtoUpdate.schemeid
)
where TLtoUpdate.ce_report = 'yes' and TLtoUpdate.schemeid is null
```

Looks there was missing the TL.id condition in the subquery.

Comment: the query doesn't get just one value.. perhaps this needs to be moved to a stored procedure of a Scalar function.. thought this would be a simple task..

Comment: Updated my original post with a new solution :)